# When was the autocorrelation function invented? And what was the motivation for it?

Tags: autocorrelation, history

I'm just very curious about the discovery process behind the autocorrelation function.

- When was it invented?
- Was it independently invented multiple times, for example?
- What was the motivation for it?

Comment: Can't answer the first two, but autocorrelation is heavily used in electronic "signal processing", to help extract data from a noisy signal, etc.  I'm guessing that the SETI folks use it a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The earliest reference for autocorrelation that I can find relates to [Udney Yule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udny_Yule), a British Statistician who among other notable accomplishments developed the Yule-Walker procedure to approximate the Partial Auto-correlation Function using the Auto-correlation Function. [Pearson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Pearson) might have been involved. Pearson as a side note was not very good at forecasting ! He predicted that Galton, rather than Charles Darwin, would be remembered as the most prodigious grandson of Erasmus Darwin.